# Microsoft Excel VBA Macro is crashing excel

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason the Macro below is crashing my Excel when it finishes. The workbook saves, and will delete the worksheet that I've asked it to. It then crashes Excel and asks if I would like to restart it. Any ideas by chance? The concept here is we have excel linked to a data cube, and want to create a "value copy" with just the values no formulas linking to the database.

```
Sub CreateVC()
'Set file path & target file name. Make sure you update the department within the file
'name in cell H2. I.E. change "Reporting - Rampage VC.xlsm" to "Reporting - VAD VC.xlsm"

Dim WBFile As Range
Set WBFile = ActiveSheet.Range("H2")

'Save current workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Save

'Save your workbook as a new file with the name at the end of the filepath in cell H2

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (WBFile)

'Moves your view to the first tab, Cognos Parameters in this case. It then moves to the next
'tab, copies the entire page, and does a paste as values. The loop will continue until the
'worksheet index # equals the total number of worksheets (it hits the last worksheet).
Worksheets(1).Select
 Do While ActiveSheet.Index <> Worksheets.Count
 ActiveSheet.Next.Select
 Cells.Select
 Selection.Copy
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
 ActiveSheet.Range("H6").Select
 Loop

'Delete the first tab, Cognos Parameters, as it is not used in the value copy. This is also
'a safeguard from creating another VC by deleting the button linked to the macro.

Worksheets(1).Delete

'Save the new VC file that has been created.

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can always guarantee that your Cognos Parameters worksheet is the first in the `Worksheets` array. If your worksheet is named "Cognos Parameters" then specifically access it with that name. Also not sure what the point of copying the cells from one worksheet to another is. Always pasting cells from one worksheet to the next will overwrite whatever exists on the target sheet. Also take a look at this [Avoid Using SELECT and ACTIVATE](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201703032054582584495)

Comment: When I see this correctly, this `Worksheets(1).Delete` deletes the original worksheet and not the copy, because the function is called in the original. Try to debug it and tell us, at which line it crashes exactly.

Comment: @Alex is my formatting incorrect? This is my first question posted. It is deleting the worksheet on the copy and not on the original. The macro works as intended, deletes the worksheet, and then Excel throws an error. I don't have the option to debug as the VBA Macro works to completion. Here is the excel error
Exception Offset: 8bfff590
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Data: 00000008. 
I've tried googling it, and was not able to find a solution.

Comment: @PeterT that is the intention of the macro. One copy is just the values from the source sheet. As we update the information on the "live" version linked to the cube, we want to dump the updated values into the "value copy" so that you do not have to link to the cube to view the data.

Comment: If each worksheet of data overwrites the previous data, then why not just loop to the last (second to last?) worksheet and copy the data once? Or simply delete all the other (older) worksheets and keep that last one with the latest data?

Comment: @PeterT I'm not really sure what you mean here. The macro starts at sheet 1, moves to sheet 2 (Sheet one has input data for the cube and does not need to be copied) and copies & pastes special values for the whole sheet, and continues on until it hits the last page(Do While ActiveSheet.Index <> Worksheets.Count).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's crashing because you have not qualified your objects in the loop, as below.

```
With ActiveSheet
    Do While .Index <> .Worksheets.Count
         .Next.Select
         .Cells.Select
         .Selection.Copy
         .Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
         .Range("H6").Select
     Loop
End With
```

I would also recommend removing that parentheses around WBFile in the SaveAs as that may be causing a problem as well.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs WBFile
```

You should also try not to use Select and ActiveSheet.